# Scala implicit conversion issue

Tags: scala, implicit-conversion

I'm having a problem with implicit conversion in the following code:

```
trait A {
  def send(s: String): String = {
    println(s)
    s
  }
}

object X {
  implicit def toB(a: A): B = new B(a)

  class B(a: A) {
    def <<(s: String): String = a send s
  }
}

object Y {
  implicit def toB(a: A): B = new B(a)

  class B(a: A) {
  }
}

object Test extends App {
  import X._
  import Y._
  val a: A = new A {}
  a << "Test"
}
```

The last statement in Test causes compile error:

```
error: value << is not a member of A
a << "Test"
```

However if I remove `import Y._` from Test, it compiles fine.

Note that in the real code both X.B and Y.B are part of Scala DSL for a Java library and I'd like to be able to use both in the same compilation unit.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like what's happening is that `Y.toB` is overriding `X.toB` when you import both in the same scope. If I put the `import Y._` *before* then `import X._`, then it works. Also, if I rename `Y`'s implicit to something else (e.g. `toYB`), then it works no matter what order you put it in.

Comment: And this is what you expect. It's like a static import in Java. If you invoked the implicit method as `toB(a)`, how would the compiler know which one you meant if the later one didn't override the other? OP should give the implicit defs names like `AtoXB` and `AtoYB` like you say, becuase `X.B` and `Y.B` are different classes.

Comment: Indeed, somehow I wasn't expecting the implicit method names to be causing the problem. I've renamed and it works fine now, thanks!